# Django-Oscar form fork - Error unknown fields (but fields are in the models)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-oscar

I am trying to fork django-oscar to change the dashboard form for product attributes, multioption. Need to have a description field for every option.

```
project/oscar_fork/catalogue/models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractAttributeOption, AbstractAttributeOptionGroup

class AbstractAttributeOption(AbstractAttributeOption):
  description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=250, blank=True)
  group = models.ForeignKey(
        'catalogue.AttributeOptionGroup',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='optionsblabla',
        verbose_name=_("Group"))

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

The models are changed with the extra field "description" in my DB, but still my form field returns cannot find this field.

```
project/oscar_fork/dashboard/catalogue/forms.py:
from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue import forms as base_forms

class AttributeOptionForm(base_forms.AttributeOptionForm):
  class Meta(base_forms.AttributeOptionForm.Meta):
    fields = ('option', 'description')
```

If I change the form.py and models.py fields directly in the Oscar app it works. Other forms can be forked that easily as shown above. Tried it with AttributeOptionGroupForm. I think there is a problem with the sequence of import. How can I solve this?

```
Error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (description) specified for AttributeOption
```

I am using django-oscar v1.6. Django v.2.08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concrete model should be named `AttributeOption` without the `'Abstract'`, otherwise oscar will not pick it up and use its own `AttributeOption` model instead, which has no description:

```
class AttributeOption(AbstractAttributeOption):
    description = ...
```

You will have to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after that.
Check the [source code](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/models.py#L66) of the `models` module that you import at the end. You will see how their dynamic model loading works:

```
if not is_model_registered('catalogue', 'AttributeOption'):
    class AttributeOption(AbstractAttributeOption):
        pass
```